# Unable to set a custom worker factory in WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I use this code to set my own worker factory:

```
val daggerWorkerFactory = DaggerWorkerFactory(toInjectInWorker)

val configuration = Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(daggerWorkerFactory)
        .build()

WorkManager.initialize(context, configuration)
```

After this code execution, I can get the WorkManager instance:

```
val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
```

The problem is that for every worker created after this point, my factory is never used. The default factory is used instead.

I can see in the API documentation that the method "WorkManager.initialize" has a note:

> Disable androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest

I cannot find any information on how to do this. Was this on some older versions of the WorkManager and they forgot to remove from the documentation or is this really necessary? If so, how?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the documentation of `WorkerManager.initialize()`

> By default, this method should not be called because `WorkManager` is
>   automatically initialized. To initialize `WorkManager` yourself, please
>   follow these steps:
>
> Disable `androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer` in your manifest In
>   `Application#onCreate` or a `ContentProvider`, call this method before
>   calling `getInstance()`

So what you need is to disable `WorkManagerInitializer` in your Manifest file:

```
  <application
        //...
        android:name=".MyApplication">
        //...
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="your-packagename.workmanager-init"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
```

And in your custom `Application` class, initialize your `WorkerManager`:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val daggerWorkerFactory = DaggerWorkerFactory(toInjectInWorker)

        val configuration = Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(daggerWorkerFactory)
            .build()

        WorkManager.initialize(context, configuration)
    }
}
```

**Note:**

By default, `WorkerManager` will add a `ContentProvider` called `WorkerManagerInitializer` with authorities set to `my-packagename.workermanager-init`.

If you pass wrong authorities in your Manifest file while disabling the `WorkerManagerInitializer`, Android will not be able to compile your manifest.

Comment: That's it! Disabling the provider in the manifest corrected the problem. Thank you Saeed for your valuable help. I just add to your answer that for compiling the code I need to add to the xml in the provider the following: tools:replace="android:authorities", otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Looks like you can actually do: `android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"`

Comment: How to create daggerWorkerFactory & toInjectInWorker object ?