# Injecting Repository in WorkManager's Worker

Tags: android, multithreading, mvvm, dependency-injection, concurrency

**The Use-Case**: I need to take feedback from users, save it in the persistent storage, in this case its Room. And after every X minutes I want to send these stored `FeedbackRequest` to the backend.

**The Solution**: I thought of using WorkManager since this action should survive the process death & also be triggered periodically. I need to get the list of `FeedbackRequest` from Room DB & use Retrofit client to send every `FeedbackRequest` to the backend.

**The Problem-Definition**:  `FeedbackRequestRepository`, which is responsible for getting the list of `FeedbackRequest`, is required in the `doWork()` method of WorkManager to get the data from Room DB. Also, I am pretty new to `Dagger2`. I am getting the mentioned error after the app open.

> AppComponent Code Snippet

```
interface AppComponent {
@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: Application): Builder

    fun build(): AppComponent
}

fun inject(scFeedbackApp: ScFeedbackApp)
fun inject(dispatchWorker: DispatchWorker)
```

}

> Repository Code Snippet

```
@Singleton
class FeedbackRequestRepository @Inject constructor(
        private val appExecutors: AppExecutors,
        private val db: ScFeedbackDB,
        private val feedbackAcknowledgeDao: FeedbackRequestDao,
        private val scFeedbackFeedbackService: SCFeedbackService
) {

...

}
```

> Worker Code Snippet

```
class DispatchWorker @Inject constructor(context:Context,
                             workerParameters: WorkerParameters,
                             var feedbackRequestRepository: FeedbackRequestRepository):
    Worker(context, workerParameters){
init {
    DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(context.applicationContext as ScFeedbackApp)
            .build().inject(this)
}
override fun doWork(): Result {

...

}
```

> Error

```
E/WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate com.scfeedback.service.responseDispatcher.DispatchWorker
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:507)
    at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:85)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:188)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/WorkerWrapper: Could not create Worker com.scfeedback.service.responseDispatcher.DispatchWorker
```

1. Does this have something to do with Dependency Inject setting.
2. If not, then where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your approach:

- You can't apply both constructor injection `@inject constructor(...)` and direct injection `DaggerAppComponent...inject(this)`
- You must use the default constructor:

So you can change your `DispatchWorker` to:

```
    class DispatchWorker constructor(context:Context,
                                 workerParameters: WorkerParameters):
        Worker(context, workerParameters){

        @Inject  lateinit var feedbackRequestRepository: FeedbackRequestRepository

    init {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(context.applicationContext as ScFeedbackApp)
                .build().inject(this)
    }
    override fun doWork(): Result {

    ...

}
```

Or use a [custom WorkerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700557/unable-to-set-a-custom-worker-factory-in-workmanager/52701693#52701693)